# How to use the same random number generator among different C++ files

Tags: c++

I am running EDAC algorithms in my main.cpp file. So I linked it with hamming.cpp, hadamard.cpp and reedsolomon.cpp. To test the performance of these algorithms, I am generating random numbers in each file separately. So in each file, this code is at the top:

```
/**
 * Random number generator functionality
 **/
std::random_device r;
std::seed_seq seed{r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r()};
std::mt19937 eng(seed);

std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist{1, 2000000};
```

Of course, we get a duplicate symbol error. So I wanted to dirty fix this at first by just changing the names of all the variables slighty, but essentially I'd have a lot of duplicate code.

I'm aware of header files and I am using them for all my .cpp files. However as far as I understand, you only use header files to declare functions and classes so the compiler knows what it is going to come across beforehand.

I also tried putting this piece of code in a randomnrgen.cpp file and then adding

```
#include randomnrgen.cpp
```

above each of the files that needed it, but that gave me the same duplicate errors. I am using the header guard trick by the way:

```
#ifndef INCLUDE_GUARD_H
#define INCLUDE_GUARD_H

#include "hamming.h"

#endif
```

So I was wondering if there is an elegant alternative solution to my dirty fix proposal? I need to access the "dist()" function with input "eng" in all of my files, so I need access to them but only want to declare them somewhere once.

Comment: You should get rid of those global variables altogether. Pass rand generator to the function requiring it as an argument.

Comment: You can declare variables without defining them with the `extern` keyword.

Comment: In `main.cpp`, before you #include the header file, put a `#define MAIN` but don't `#define MAIN` in your other translation units. Then inside your include file, if MAIN is defined, declare your random generators, whereas if MAIN is not defined, precede the random generators with `extern`.

Comment: Your comments brought me to 2 solutions: passing a function pointer around to the functions that need it, and another one using "extern". Now I just need to decide which one is better, but it's a lot cleaner than duplicate code. Thank you @ everyone

Comment: You should never include a cpp file from another one. Only header files should ever be shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is okay to have global random number generator.

See:

1. [Using same random number generator across multiple functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930182/using-same-random-number-generator-across-multiple-functions),
2. [RNGs and global variable avoidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660092/rngs-and-global-variable-avoidance).

And if you are looking for how to do it:

[How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files)